# How to log messages in Java web app and view logs by session, request, in a tree?

Tags: java, logging, web-applications, log-analysis

Currently, in my web app logs, I have big text files full of messages. They are difficult to use in debugging and analysis. I'm imagining the following, and I'm wondering, does it already exist, or do I need to build it?

I want to have log messages associated with the current request and session so that I can view a log in a UI as a collapsible tree.  At the summary level I might view by user/session and under those see requests with the total time spent in the request.  From there I can drill down into a request and see the log messages at deeper levels.  Requests that contain warnings or errors would be highlighted or selectable with a filter.

I also want the system to be extensible and not a black box. I want to connect asynchronous tasks to sessions/requests even if those things were happening in other threads.  And I want to integrate this with client side Javascript errors. That is another issue, but the point is I need something extensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using following pattern:

- My Log4j pattern is using [MDC](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html) - %d{ISO8601} %p [%X{REQUEST_ID}][%X{SESSION_ID}][%X{USER}] %class %m%n
- In application for every request  I'm using [MDC.put()](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/MDC.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method to set REQUEST_ID, SESSION_ID, USER

  ```
  MDC.put("SESSIONION_ID", sessionId);
  MDC.put("REQUEST_ID", requestId);
  MDC.put("USER", user);
  ```
- I have defined this log pattern in [OtrosLogViewer](https://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/Log4jPatternLayout). Your log pattern definition should looks like:

  ```
  type=log4j
  pattern=TIMESTAMP LEVEL [PROP(REQUEST_ID)][PROP(SESSION_ID)][PROP(USER)] CLASS MESSAGE
  dateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS
  name="MyAppLog"
  charset=UTF-8
  ```
- I open logs with [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer) which allows me to easy filter by property REQUEST_ID, SESSIONS_ID or USER_ID. It can also filter logs by class, date, thread, etc. Logs can be open from [remote servers using SFTP, FTP, SMB](https://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/LocalAndRemote)
- Additionally you can integrate [OtrosLogViewer with your Intellij](https://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/wiki/JumpToCode). See example on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbOFF56_7-A?hd=1

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of OtrosLogViewer